# Collapse tabs - jumping to opened tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have accordion tabs, this accordion is setted to max 1 open tab, so if I opened one tab, and then I open other tab, the first tab auto collapsing, and eveyrthing works great, but if I have problem: when first tab have long content and user open other tab, then first tab hide, and scroll of page goes much lower than opened tab, I want to add some jump to the opened tab.

My website in development: http://styro.fm4.pl/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("label").click(function() {
    $('html, body').delay(1000).animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
.tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 4em;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 2.5;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
}

.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .35s;
  -o-transition: max-height .35s;
  transition: max-height .35s;
  padding: 0px 20px 00px 20px;
}

input:checked~.tab-content {
  max-height: 9000px;
}

label::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 23px;
  top: 3px;
  display: block;
  width: 31px;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}

input[type=radio]+label::after {
  content: url(../images/up.png);
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  color: #e79f39;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">
  <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tabs2">
  <label for="tab-1">Tab 1</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    Content<div style="height:2000px;">spaace</div>space
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tabs2">
  <label for="tab-2">Tab 2</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
<div style="height:2000px;">blank space</div>blank space
```

But problem with this jQuery code is that, this works, but it ignore that the first tab is hiding, so the new opened tab is in different place, so user jumps to another much lower place then tab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just remove `<div style="height:2000px;">blank space</div>` from your code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("label").click(function() {
    $('html, body').delay(1000).animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
.tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 4em;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 2.5;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
}

.tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .35s;
  -o-transition: max-height .35s;
  transition: max-height .35s;
  padding: 0px 20px 00px 20px;
}

input:checked~.tab-content {
  max-height: 9000px;
}

label::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 23px;
  top: 3px;
  display: block;
  width: 31px;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}

input[type=radio]+label::after {
  content: url(../images/up.png);
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  color: #e79f39;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">
  <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tabs2">
  <label for="tab-1">Tab 1</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    Content<div style="height:2000px;">spaace</div>space
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab">
  <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tabs2">
  <label for="tab-2">Tab 2</label>
  <div class="tab-content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
blank space
```

Comment: But this imitates a content in this tab, please see www.styro.fm4.pl and Tab called "Listwy i gzymsy" - there is a lot of content.